# Write a program that lists the sum of the first x palindromes

Tags: sequence, fibonacci, palindrome

I need to write a program that has the sum of the first x palindromes. I really have absolutely no idea how to do this. Can someone write a program (any language, but please indicate) that does this?

Currently, I can print out the first 9000 palindromes with this Haskell program. How could I edit it so that it generates ALL first 9000 palindromes instead of the xth palindrome?

```
prefixes 0 = [[k] | k <-['1'..'9']]
prefixes n = [k:s | s <- prefixes (n-1), k <- ['0'..'9']]
p n = 
  [ reverse s ++ tail s | s <- prefixes n ] ++
  [ reverse s ++ s | s <- prefixes n ] ++ 
  p (n+1)
allpals = [[]] ++ p 0

main = do print (allpals !! 9000)
```

BONUS CHALLENGE: How about the sum of the palindromes in the first x numbers of the fibonacci sequence? >:)

Comment: A palindrome is a number like 11, 22, 101, 334433, 10201, etc.; any number that can be read forward and backwards. If you're referring to the first question, the program I'm looking for would be able to take the first x palindromes and add them together. For example, if I were to set x as 10, the program would take 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 101, and add them together.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Give it a shot, and if there's a specific problem you run into, SO is a good place to turn. It sounds like this is a programming fundamentals assignment, and many here would rather help you learn if there's a way to do so without simply giving the answer.

Comment: This is not a site where you post your homework problems and expect people to solve them for you.  This is a site where, if you show legitimate effort, you will receive almost unlimited help getting you past the parts you don't understand.

Comment: Guys, don't be too harsh with him, let's give him the thought process. He just intends to start programming, we have all been there. Vulcanis, I will give you some basic thoughts which will hopefully guide you to the solution. This site is not for asking for complete solutions.

Comment: @vulcanis, you mean the code you have written so far, right?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the first problem first. Let's suppose you have a function which returns the next palindrome of a palindrome received as parameter. If you had such a function, you could do something like this:

```
function getPalindromeSum(nr)
    sum <- 0
    palindrome <- 0
    while (nr > 0) do
        sum <- sum + palindrome
        palindrome <- nextPalindrome(palindrome)
        nr <- nr - 1
    end while
    return palindrome
end function
```

So, we have reduced the problem-space. Our new question is: How can we find the next palindrome. This is how you should do it:

- you check the number of digits of palindrome
- if it is odd, then check the middle digit. If it is smaller than 9, then add one to the middle digit and leave the other digits intact
- if it is odd, but its middle digit was 9, then take the first half of the digits, including the middle digit and add one to this number. If the number of digits do not increase, then reverse the first half of the result (excluding the middle digit) and that will be the second half
- if it is odd, but its middle digit was 9 and after adding 1 to the first half, including the middle number the number of digits increased, then you reverse the first half (in this case, including the middle number) and this will be the second half
- if it is not odd, then take the first half and increment it. If the number of digits does not increase, then reverse it and that will be the second half
- if it is not odd and after the incrementation the number of digits increases, then reverse the number, that will be the second half and you need a new 0 into the middle

EDIT:
Sum of the palindromes from the first n elements in the fibonacci sequence

You can use [Binet's formula](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibFormula.html#formula) to get the n'th Fibonacci number and round the result to the nearest integer or you can calculate it recursively. If you choose Binet's formula, then it is advisable to have the current used power of Phi and phi and multiply them with Phi and phi, respectively. If you choose the traditional way (which is advisable in this particular case), then you need to have the two former fibonacci number. Anyway, this is how it should be done (I have chosen the traditional way in my solution):

```
function palindromesInFibo(nr)
    formerFormer <- -1
    former <- 1
    sum <- 0
    while nr > 0 do
        aux <- palindrome
        palindrome <- formerFormer + former
        formerFormer <- former
        former <- aux
        sum <- sum + palindrome
    end while
end function
```

Also, if you want to sum the first n palindromes in the Fibonacci sequence, you just need to change your while condition accordingly.

**Also, I must emphasize that the first n palindromes in the Fibonacci sequence and the palindromes in the first n Fibonacci numbers with a finite n requires is to compromise and specify that we search for palindromes either strictly or unstrictly with positive indexes. If we do not make this compromise, then these questions do not make sense.**